# read excelsheet in azure uploaded as a blob

Tags: c#, azure

I am using FileUpload control of asp.net and uploading the excel with some data. I can't save it in some folder. I can have stream of excel sheet file or I can have Blobstream after uploading excel as a blob. Now I want to convert that excel sheets 1st sheet to datatable so how shall I do that? I am using C# .NET. I don't want to use Interop library. I can use external libraries. Oledb connection is getting failed since I don't have any physical path of excel as a data source. I tried following links:

1) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14639/Fast-Excel-file-reader-with-basic-functionality

2) http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of Excel file you can use the examples you posted or go for the OpenXML alternative (for xlsx files): http://openexcel.codeplex.com/

Now, the problem with the physical path is easy to solve. Saving the file to blob storage is great. But if you want, you can **also** save it in a local resource to have it locally. This will allow you to process the file using a simple OleDb connection. Once you're done with the file, you can just delete it from the local resource (it will still be available in the blob storage since you also uploaded it there).

Don't forget to have some kind of clean up mechanism in case your processing fails. You wouldn't want to end up with a disk filled with temporary files (even though it could take a while before this happens).

Read more on local resources here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx

Comment: In openexcel you told I before hand must know the rows and columns in the excel sheet which is not possible. But yes about the local storage it worked well. Thanks for the local storage help. Now I can search for any solution. Initially I was not searching for such solutions.

Comment: I changed my app pool settings to 32 bit and oledb connection started working so I used that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenXML SDK which is an officially suggested way of working with MS Office documents - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: I don't want to install something on the azure server so this is not prefferable solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I first created local storage as per the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx

suggested by Sandrino above. Thanks Sandrino for this. Then I used oledb connection and it gave me an error "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 dll is not registered". Then I logged on to the azure server and in the IIS changed app pool configuration for 32-bit. To change app pool to 32-bit refer the following link:

http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/windows-2008-the-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/

Answer (score 0):

The approach you followed is not the correct one, as you said  you logged on to azure and changed, the VM which is running on azure is not the permanent one for you. For any updates you are going to get new VM machine. you might have to find turn around for this, instead of modifying manually.  You can make use of the startup tasks in your azure app.  See the link below it may help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx