# Upload Excel 2013 Workbook to website hosted on Azure

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, azure-web-app-service, excel-interop

Does anyone have guidance and/or example code (which would be awesome) on how I would go about the following?

With a Web application using C# / ASP.NET MVC and hosted on Azure:

1. Allow a user to upload an Excel Workbook (multiple worksheets) via a web page UI
2. Populate a Dataset by reading in the worksheets so I can then process the data

Couple of things I'm unclear on:

1. I've read that Azure doesn't have ACEOLEDB, which is what Excel 2007+ requires, and I'd have to use OPEN XML SDK. Is this true? Is this the only way?
2. Is it possible to read the file into memory and not actually save it to Azure storage?

I DO NOT need to modify the uploaded spreadsheet. Only read the data in and then throw the spreadsheet away.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's many questions in one post, let me see if we can tackle them one by one

> With a Web application using C# / ASP.NET MVC and hosted on Azure:
>   1.Allow a user to upload an Excel Workbook (multiple worksheets) via a web page UI
>   2.Populate a Dataset by reading in the worksheets so I can then process the data
>
> Couple of things I'm unclear on:
>   1.I've read that Azure doesn't have ACEOLEDB, which is what Excel 2007+ requires, and I'd have to use OPEN XML SDK. Is this true? Is
>   this the only way?
>   2.Is it possible to read the file into memory and not actually save it to Azure storage?

1/2. You can allow a user to upload the excel workbook to some /temp location and once you have read you can choose to do the cleanup, you can also write a script which can do the cleanup of the files which couldn't get deleted from /temp for whatever reasons.
Alternatively if you want to keep the files, you should store them in Azure Stoarge, and fetch/read when you need to.
check out this thread [read excelsheet in azure uploaded as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209171/read-excelsheet-in-azure-uploaded-as-a-blob) 
By default when you upload a file it is wrote into local disk and one later chooses to save the files to azure storage or whatever places.

2. Reading the excel - you can use any of the nugget packages given here http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel and read the excel file, I prefer Gembox and NPOI

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/12/how-to-upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-razor.html